# reverse how vertical bar chart is drawn

Tags: d3.js

How can I reverse how my vertical bar is drawn?
I want it to be drawn from the bottom to the top.
It is important to maintain the right representation of the dataset

https://jsfiddle.net/adai183/ztsh1ptx/

```
var dataset = [ 10, 80, 5, 5];

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "rgb(250, 128, 114)")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - (d * 4);
    })
    .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition().duration(750).ease("linear")
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d * 4;
});
```

Comment: but why? Renderers generally start at the top of a page and work down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
    .attr("y",  function(d) {
        return h; //set y to max height
    })
    .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
    .attr("height", 0)//height of the bars initially is 0
    .transition().duration(750).ease("linear")//on transition
    .attr("y",  function(d) {
        return d*4;//set the y to its value
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return h - (d * 4);//set the height to max height - y's value
})
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/xy1rLcsy/)

**EDIT**

For solving that problem make a scale for y:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([h, 0])
        .domain([0,100]);//since values vary between 0 and 100
```

Now use this scale to give height to your bar chart.

```
.transition().duration(750).ease("linear")
    .attr("y",  function(d) {
        return y(d);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return h - y(d);
})
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/5wdcjy3s/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But there is one problem the bars are not representing the data accurately anymore. The rect with the highest value is actually drawn with the smalles height. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/adai183/zvyzp1e4/

Comment: Updated my answer check my **EDIT** section.